# Multiple Field Widget instances on the same page, validation problem

Tags: entities

I have multiple instances of the same field widget attached to different entity forms on the same page. On validating one of these forms, when I set form_set_error($field_name, '...'), every one of these widgets get highlighted. Is there a way to get around this somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [API page for form_set_error](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--form.inc/function/form_set_error/7). This bit should help you out:

> $name The name of the form element. If the #parents property of your form element is array('foo', 'bar', 'baz') then you may set an error on 'foo' or 'foo][bar][baz'. Setting an error on 'foo' sets an error for every element where the #parents array starts with 'foo'.

In your case you'll just want to make sure that the parent item is different for each instance of that field, then set the error with `form_set_error($parent_name . '][' . $field_name, '...')`

Comment: Forgot to add this in the question itself but I don't want to change #parents as that would change the way I access the value of the field(s) in different parts of the code. I just want to uniquely replace the name of the fields on the client-side so that the validator can use that just to flag the correct element. Do you think this can be done?